# Windows Updates - Uninstall keys location in the registry under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

In other OS like XP, the uninstall keys where located at:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

But for the Windows Updates, it seems that are not stored here. Anyone knows where's the new location?

Answer (score 2):

That is their location. That's where mine are, and I'm on Windows 7 32bit